# HTML select with angularjs ng-options to MVC Model, can't do it

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, html-select

I'm trying to insert my selected value to MVC model.

I saw some answers with `@Html.DropDownList` but i can't figure it out.

this is my select code :

```
Manufacturer : <select ng-model="UserCarManufacturer" ng-options="I.id as I.name for I in CountryList" ng-change="GetState()" class="form-control" id="CarManId">
                  <option value="">Select Manufacturer</option>
               </select>
              {{UserCarManufacturer}}
```

`{{UserCarManufacturer}}` is the selection id.

I just want to be clear, I want to insert the selected value to this model : `@model CreatorModel`

Comment: You don't need the option tag if you are using ng-options. Also for your model you need an object (not just a string/number like an id)

Comment: i have this MVC model "UserModel", inside this model i have ManufactureId (int).
i need to insert the DP value into the MVC model. like in
 "@Html.TextBoxFor"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after few days of searching, I didn't find a way to it so I made this solution:

make an unvisiable "  @Html.TextBoxFor" and set the value in the TextBox each time value change in the HTML select.

this is the code I added, and it works great :

```
<div class="form-group" style="visibility:hidden;display:none">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserCarModel, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "UserCarModel", @placeholder = "UserCarModel" })
</div>
```

and in JS I added:

```
var lbCarMan = document.getElementById("UserCarManufacturer");
lbCarMan.value = $scope.CarManufacturerID;
```